# Generating and collaborating on network map diagrams?

Tags: software-rec, osx-lion, file-format, cross-platform

I have to turn out some network topology maps for very large networks. I'd like the format for the maps to be something other people can also edit and contribute to regardless of what software I'm using on my Mac to build them. I don't mind spending money on my end for software, but I can't require that my clients spend any money. I also can't promise my clients are also using OS X -- they could be running Linux or Windows.

Is there a best software application on OS X for producing maps that I can share with other, non-OS X, users?

Is there a best format for sharing topology maps that I should use when exporting the maps to disk?

Comment: Is VMware Fusion, Windows and whatever your customers use a feasible solution?

Comment: Probably not. I suspect some would have Visio, others are OS X based as well, and then some are Linux (Ubuntu mainly). It's about an even 3-way split. Lots of academics and public institutions.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you find a better answer, but one option might be to use the drawing tool in google docs. Overview here https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185180&topic=29442&rd=1

Comment: I'm considering this. My experience thus far with the diagram tool in GDocs has been less than positive though. Nice for the quick and simple stuff, poor for the big and complicated stuff.